# How to create function to select continuous variables in Python?

Tags: python

I want to find a method so that I can separate discrete variable from continuous variable in Integer data type in Python. Suppose I have data set comprising row id, class and amount, and when I imported it into Python the data type shown as int64 for all there columns.

But I want to make function in Python so that it automatically select variables with continuous data type i.e amount only.

Comment: What exactly the criteria is? For example if you have a column with the values 1,2,3,4 - it can be a discrete variable or a continuous variable...

Comment: see I have Row id column which is sequence of number 1,2,3,4 and so on. and I have class column with label 1,2,3 and then I have Amount column which is integer type but it is continuous variable. @theletz

Comment: Assuming you want integer for "discrete" variable (1, 2, 3, ..) and float for "continuous "variable (1.23, 5.77, 8.99, ...), Maybe you can use pandas `infer_dtype` to automatically decide the type.

Comment: @Daniser I know the data type of the columns, but the problem is in python integer data type is characterized by not having decimal and I want to segregate continuous variable from discrete variable in integer data type only.